# Applying a third party plugin preset to just the bridge section

Tags: logic-pro, plugin, automation, effect, track

I need to apply a preset from Nectar on a vocal track, but only to the bridge.  I have tried to use automation, but I am presented with a huge list of parameters when trying to select  the nectar preset.

Do I have to slice and move the bridge section to it's own track in order to apply the pluggin preset to just the bridge?

Thanks!

Comment: You give a solution to your own question within the text itself, what is it that you want to know exactly?

Comment: This is really something that could be solved by reading the manual. There's usually a way to filter the list to parameters you want.

Comment: As Brendan mentioned, this is not a sound design question as per the FAQ, but is simply a learning Nectar question. Your best bet is to read the manual or watch online nectar tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Tracking is the easiest and normal Way if you have different FX for one Instrument. Another way is to add both fx settings after each other and then Automate wet/dry.

Good Day